# Is it "It is likely to happen" or "It is likely that that happen?"

Tags: translation

- It is likely to happen.
- It is likely that that happen.

Which sentence is correct? Because, in French, we say, "*Il est probable **que cela** se produise*", and, in English, **"que" and "cela" are both "that"**.

Therefore, it looks repetitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

> It /this is likely to happen.

Perfectly correct.

For your second sentence you can avoid repetition very simply:

> It is likely that this will happen.

However, the second use is less idiomatic.

Comment: However, the subjunctive is not used after "it is likely that", so the OP's second example is not good English.

Comment: That it is likely that that should be used repetitively is the problem with that writer, not that word.

Comment: I think the second sentence would be standard English actually if _likely_ is replaced with _wished_, for then the subjunctive comes into play.

Comment: Yes, I agree with all comments. Since you have indicated this in your comments, would it be okay not to edit my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct, provided you add an s; however they do not mean the same thing.

- It is likely to happen.
- It is likely that this/that happens. ([ref. 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+likely+that+this+happens&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20likely%20that%20this%20happens%3B%2Cc0), [ref. 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20likely%20that%20this%20happens%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

In the first sentence you are making a judgement on the possibility of it happening in the future.
In the second, because you are using the state present, you are making a judgement on the possibility of it happening over a period of time that starts an indefinite time in the past, is continued in the present, and extends an indefinite time into the future.